# Finding Cartesian coordinates of remaining vertices of triangle, given a vertex and an angle

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems, angle

I have an isosceles triangle $ABC$, where the height $h$ and the angle at vertex $A$ are known. The Cartesian coordinates of vertex $A$ are also known to be $\left(x,y\right)$. is it possible to find the coordinates of the remaining vertices?

[Triangle ABC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HJAf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It is not possible, because you have the same data if the triangle is rotated around $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find the coordinates of the remaining two vertices.

Rotate the triangle about A. The height remains the same. Angle A remains the same. The coordinates of A remain the same but the coordinates of B and C change.

Therefore, there is not enough information to find the coordinates of the remaining vertices.